# Inserting datetime type char from form into database

Tags: c#, database, string, datetime, insert

I'm trying to insert a datetime value into my database table, but I'm ancountring a problem.
Each time I try to do this, this message pops up:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
> The statement has been terminated.

This is my code:

```
public static void  DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)
{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
  
}
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='c:\users\***\***\visual studio 2010\Projects\***\***\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        cn.Open();
        string[] dateArr = dateBox.Text.Split('/');
        int[] dateInt = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            dateInt[i] = Int16.Parse(dateArr[i]);
            MessageBox.Show(dateInt[i]+"");
        }
        DateTime date = new DateTime(dateInt[2],dateInt[1],dateInt[0]);
        
        string sql = "INSERT INTO existProducts(name,date,price,amount) VALUES ('" + nameBox.Text + "','" + date + "','" + priceBox.Text + "','" + amountBox.Text + "')";

        MyAdoHelper.DoQuery("Database.mdf", sql);
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
       
        cn.Close();
    }
```

> Note 1: I had an exeption handling but I removed it because I always had
> to handle this exception and the program didn't run well.
>
> Note 2: I censored the connection string, but there is a connection and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, but what the heck do you say about exception? "I always had to handle this exception". Yes, so ignorance now is good? You had an exception, you removed the handling and you do not tell us the exception? HELLO? My house burned down, I don't like calling firefighters, can you help?

Comment: to prevent question like this. sorry for mentioning that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and *most probabbly* your problem wil be solved, **and** (another important thing)  you will be secure yourself from the *injection atack* too.

Comment: What is SqlParameter? I have never heard about this before (I'm a little newbie)

Comment: @user1842086: follow the link provided and see examples. This is a *secure* way to inject values into the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

Using string date values in your insert statement.....

Use SqlParameters in your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO existProducts (name,date,price,amount) VALUES (@name, @date, @price, @amount)


public static void  DoQuery(string fileName, string name, DateTime date, float price, float amount)
{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.Paramaters.AddWithValue("name", name);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date);
    ...
    ...
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
    conn.Close();

}
```